# Nativescript - webpack snapshotting on Android confusion

Tags: webpack, nativescript

I'd like to enable webpack snapshot for my Android app.

Read the document and confused by the paragraph below.

1) Because heap snapshots are a feature of V8, you can only use this feature as part of your NativeScript Android builds. A similar feature is not available for NativeScript iOS builds. 2) Under the hood, the NativeScript snapshot generator uses a V8 tool called mksnapshot. The mksnapshot tool only supports macOS and Linux, and therefore at the moment you are unable to use the --snapshot flag as part of your builds on Windows. On Windows-based development machine the NativeScript CLI ignores the --snapshot flag.

Snapshots are only available on Android - understand that ok.

But to enable it, I can't do it from my Windows PC - has to be done from Mac OS pc?

Comment: The mksnapshot tools that generate V8 snapshot blobs for x86, arm32, and arm64 on Android cannot be built or ran on Windows, a limitation imposed by the V8 team.

Comment: That's too bad because I bet of the of the Android dev gets done on Windows. Any chance of getting on Windows?

Comment: It's not something that we can do "just like that" - cross compile the V8 Virtual machine targeting android ABIs on Windows. If we could, we'd do it.

Comment: Understand...I'll try to get the Android requirements running on my Mac. Last time had some problems.